# Convert multiple nvarchar values to int

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm working on an SSRS report where users can type in multiple numbers to bring back relevant data. The requirement is to enable users to be able to input multiple values.

So I have a param `@serial` which can either me just one value or anything upto 100

I can't seem to figure out how to convert each value from `nvarchar` to `int`

I've tried `SET @Serials = CONVERT(INT,@Serials)` but I get the following error message

> Conversation fail when converting the `nvarchar` value '123 456' to data type `int`

If I use `@serial` as `int` then I get the following error message

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values spevified in the VALUES caluse. The number of values in the VALUES caluse must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement

The error above is when I'm inserting into a temp table at the below line of code

```
INSERT INTO @Temp
(TMP_SerialNo)
VALUES (@serial)
```

If someone guide me where I'm going wrong I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: I think you went wrong by trying to use a multivalued parameter as values for a temporary table

Comment: @Lamak any suggestion how I else I would go about it

Comment: not without knowing what you are actually using those values for

Comment: But  '123 456' is not a number ... try removing a white space to make it a number and then insert it into table

Comment: SSRS is not designed to alter anyway the underlying database, it is a reporting engine. However you can use a text data type parameter, if your users type `123, 456` it will try to insert a row with that values. Note your user must input many values as columns your table has.

Comment: @Lamak The values in the temp table are used to narrow down the search by cross referencing the input serial number to various other tables

Comment: @Veljko89 op is probably selecting the values `123` and `456` from a multivalued parameter

Comment: @Code The way to use a multivalued parameter would be `SELECT some_columns FROM some_table WHERE some_other_column IN (@Your_Parameter)`

Comment: @Lamak Thanks for your suggestion, I changed my insert statement and I've got it working by using the IN operator. If you post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this in an SSRS report is to add a cast to put it in int.
You can't insert values into a SSRS report, only a SQL Table.

I add this at the beginning (before the select):

```
  DECLARE @temp_Status integer;
    set @temp_Status = CAST(SomeStatus as int);
    And then use everywhere the var @temp_Status.
```

Comment: This will only convert the first value and not the second.

Comment: Are you referring to the 456 in your question?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm referring to

Comment: Either your data is wrong or your using some sort of parameter that has multiple values. '123 456' is simply not an int because of the spacing, you might be able to use sql concatenate to join them together if that's really a '123456'. If you are meaning '123,456' then can you try a numeric instead of an int if you can't concat them?